# How to dynamically scale yAxis with initial value as a number

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I know this will be an easy job for many, but I can't figure out how can I scale yAxis with initial value as a dynamic value got as input and all other values of yAxis must change according to the initial value. Please help me out of it.

Comment: if its about d3 you can read range and domains. Very hard to give solid answer without reference and code.

Comment: You can use yAxis.update() method and inside you may scale your axis with new min and max values. I am not sure what you would like to achieve. Could you give more specific information about your issue? Maybe drawing that will show your idea?